# How to download Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) from Google Code?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to learn how to use GCM and I want download the simple app. I'm following the instructions here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html.

> Using App Engine for Java
>
> To set up the server using a standard App Engine for Java:
>
> 1. **Get the files from the open source site, as described above.**

I entered the link - https://code.google.com/p/gcm/ but there is no download there, and I don't have Git (and I don't know how to use it..).

Can someone please explain how to download it or give me a link or something?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The home page for Git is http://git-scm.com/. The downloads page for Git is http://git-scm.com/downloads, and that page also contains links to other Git clients. Once you have a Git client set up, you can use it to clone the repository.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very very late answer for this. But today I have seen your question here and found that here is no answer other then you, So giving a solution to it. May be it will be useful to other's.

- Open URL https://code.google.com/p/gcm/
- Now click on source tab, and go to Browse tab just below the source
  tab.
- Now you have directories section in left window that have all sample
  projects for gcm.
- Select any project from there and hit the Download zip link, Finally
  you have done it.
- Direct URL to download the sample code for GCM. [here](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution!
You can also download GCM from the SDK Manager.